# Firefox Developer Edition not showing quick watch pop up window when hovered over variable

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools, javascript-debugger, firefox-developer-edition

I just installed Firefox Developer Edition (V 52.0a2 (2017-01-03) (32-bit)). I tried to debug the JS file and as usual hovered over the JS variable. I was expecting a pop to appear with a quick watch but nothing appeared. Then I tried to right click the variable and expected a context menu with option to add variable to the watch but that is also not there, instead I got two options "Remove Breakpoint", "Edit Breakpoint". All these things were working in older versions of FF Developer edition. What I am missing here or they simply removed "add to watch" option (which I don't think so for all valid reasons.)[image]

Comment: to be honest, debugging JS in 52 (current developer version) is far harder than it used to be, for this and other reasons - not sure why mozilla have screwed debugging so badly

Comment: quick solution ... about:config and set `devtools.debugger.new-debugger-frontend` to **false**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is a [new debugger UI](https://github.com/devtools-html/debugger.html) developed independently from Firefox, which implements new features but is still missing some of the features of the old UI.

The [watch expression features](https://github.com/devtools-html/debugger.html/issues/916) (and with them the [context menu option](https://github.com/devtools-html/debugger.html/issues/1596)) were obviously already reimplemented, but not merged into the Firefox sources yet. See also [bug 1319402](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1319402).